# I have 2 interger value, which contain '-' ,want to split it.. but getting error int doesn't contain split attribute

Tags: python

```
def splitIn(x):
   t = x. Split('-')
   return (t[0] + t[1])/2

splitIn(7-8)
```

I have 2 interger value, which contain '-' ,want to split it.. but getting error int doesn't contain split attribute

Comment: `split` is a method of strings. You are passing `7-8 = -1` to your function.

Comment: You should call your function like `splitIn('7-8')` note the quotes to pass a `str` properly

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert your numbers to `String` first. What you are doing is essentially passing -1 to the function.

```
splitIn('7-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up some types like no quotes around the `7-8` and `split()` returns a `string` not an `int` so you can't add them. Try this code:

```
def splitIn(x):
   t = x.split('-')
   return (int(t[0]) + int(t[1]))/2

print(splitIn('7-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Split is an inbuilt function of class type string. Since you're passing an integer type object you would obviously get an error.

Option 1:-

```
def splitIn(x): 
    t = str(x).split('-') 
    return (t[0] + t[1])
 splitIn(7-8)
```

Comment: This won't work. 7-8 will be evaluated to -1 before the call to splitIn.